# Regex to exclude non-ASCII but keep Nordic characters

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a macro in which I use Regex to strip a text of all non-ASCII characters (in order to create folder names).

I am relatively new to Regex and I was wondering how to strip all non-ASCII but still include Nordic characters, as the macro goes through Scandinavian data. Basically, I would need to include characters 128 to 165 from [**this table**](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp865.html)

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Function GetStrippedText(txt As String) As String
    Dim regEx As Object

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regEx.Pattern = "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
    GetStrippedText = regEx.Replace(txt, "")

End Function
```

I understand that I need to include this range in there somehow `"[^\u0000-\u007F]"`, I just don't know where to find the associated code or how to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge I think there are a few points here to highlight:

- Not all extended (or non-) ASCII tables follow the same character encoding. The table you linked seems to follow CP437, and Excel follows UTF-8 (Unicode), which you can test using the `UNICODE` function in Excel. [Here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) is a link to see the difference it makes in Hex-codes. So you most likely need to pick a range of interest within the "Latin-1 Supplement" which can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). For this exercise I went with characters from `À-ÿ` which is range: `u00C0-\u00FF`
- Next, your current character class covers normal ASCII characters, however I believe you might just be interested in `0020-007F` as you probably don't want to include `0000-001F`.
- Thirdly, you did not set the `Global` parameter to `True` which means your current UDF will only replace the first character it finds outside your character class. So you'll need to set this parameter to replace **all** characters outside defined character class.

So to conclude, the below might work for you:

```
Public Function GetStrippedText(txt As String) As String
    Dim regEx As Object

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regEx.Global = True
    regEx.Pattern = "[^\u0020-\u007F\u00C0-\u00FF]"
    GetStrippedText = regEx.Replace(txt, "")

End Function
```

For your understanding; `[^\u0020-\u007F\u00C0-\u00FF]` means:

- `[....]` - The brackets tell us this is a character class
- `^` - The caret means it's a negated character class
- `\u0020-\u007F` - means the characters run from index 32 till index 127 **and** `\u00C0-\u00FF` runs from 192 till 255.

In this same fashion you can extend the amount of character ranges.

---

***Note1:*** Instead of Unicode, you could also just use the Hex codes: `"[^\x20-\x7F\xC0-\xFF]"`

***Note2:*** You could also create a character class without Unicode or Hex ranges. Simply concatenate the characters of interest instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It's exactly what i was searching for: Not only does the code you provided work, but I actually understand 100% what it does and how to use this in the future. Thanks for both links also, those charts really were the missing piece for me. Cheers!

Comment: @AlexBrollo, it's a pleasure. I also needed to plunge into the matter, but it was fun. Good question.